# Getting int as decimal(22,0) using ojdbc6 jar

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

As per my understanding in oracle 11g,

**INTEGER is equivalent to NUMBER(38,0)**

I am using `squirrel-sql-3.6` client to check data and metadata of oracle tables.

I created a table using SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE "ABC"."TABLE01"
(
   NUM_INT INTEGER
)
;
```

When I clicked to get Create Table Script, it gave me :

```
CREATE TABLE "ABC"."TABLE01"
(
   NUM_INT decimal(22,0)
)
;
```

I am expecting NUM_INT of type decimal(38,0)

I am using **Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.1) `ojdbc6.jar`**

I also tried using Java code:

```
 try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUri, userName, password);) {
         DatabaseMetaData metadata = con.getMetaData();
         ResultSet rs = metadata.getColumns(schemaName, null, tableName, null);

       } catch (SQLException e) {
         LOG.info("SQLException. Caused By: " + e);
}
```

output:

```
ordinalPosition:1
columnName:NUM_INT 
dataType:NUMBER 
precision:22 
scale:0 
columnSize:22 
nullable:false 
foreignKey:false 
autoIncrement:false
```

Is this a problem of this particular version of jar?

P.S. I am using Java 7

Comment: You said yourself above, when you clicked "Create Table Script" it told you it was a `decimal(22,0)`. So why are you suspecting the jar??

Comment: @dcsohl Don't you think it should be `decimal(38,0)`?

Comment: I never said what I thought it should be. But you created it with a SQL script, and you checked it by asking the database to create the table script, and it told you `decimal(22,0)`. So what does Java have to do with any of this?

Comment: @dcsohl there is no point in getting angry my friend. Please read the question again peacefully. I think the problem lies with this ojdbc6.jar (11.2.0.1) . I tested via squirrel and Java JDBC got same (22,0) but as per docs, It should be (38,0)

Comment: Is there any reason in your specific case to hard-code the size of the resulting number? The usual declaration in Oracle SQL is simply `NUM_INT number` (not "integer" or "decimal" or anything like that, and the precision and scale are not included unless you have a good reason to include them).

Comment: Nobody's angry, but you aren't answering my question. For the third time, why do you think the ojdbc jar has anything to do with it? You didn't create the database with it, and you queried the database with another tool. So why?

Comment: @dcsohl I created the table via squirrel client and querying the database using same client

Comment: It is possible that "integer" from java or whatever other context is translated to NUMBER(22,0) or DECIMAL(22,0) because an "integer" is 64 binary bits, and 2^64 is around 10^20, so there is no reason to reserve more than 22 decimal digits to store anything that is converted from an int64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some confusion between the number of decimal digits that can displayed and the number of bytes those digits are stored in.

Looking at the [`NUMBER` data type documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00222):

> **NUMBER Datatype**
>
> Specify a fixed-point number using the following form:
>
> ```
> NUMBER(p,s)
> ```
>
> where:
>
> - `p` is the precision, or the total number of significant decimal digits, where the most significant digit is the left-most nonzero digit, and the least significant digit is the right-most known digit. Oracle guarantees the portability of numbers with precision of up to 20 base-100 digits, which is equivalent to 39 or 40 decimal digits depending on the position of the decimal point.
> - `s` is the scale, or the number of digits from the decimal point to the least significant digit. The scale can range from -84 to 127.

and [internally](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#sthref3819):

> **Internal Numeric Format**
>
> Oracle stores numeric data in variable-length format. Each value is stored in scientific notation, with 1 byte used to store the exponent and up to 20 bytes to store the mantissa. The resulting value is limited to 38 digits of precision. Oracle does not store leading and trailing zeros. For example, the number 412 is stored in a format similar to 4.12 x 102, with 1 byte used to store the exponent(2) and 2 bytes used to store the three significant digits of the mantissa(4,1,2). Negative numbers include the sign in their length.
>   So Oracle stores a `NUMBER(38)` in 22 bytes - the most-significant digits of the number are stored using 20 base-100 digits (1-byte each) and the rest for the number's precision (although Oracle only guarantees to store up to 38 decimal digits).

The driver is probably converting the value from Oracle's base-100 format (counting digits) to a decimal floating-point representation (counting bytes).

Answer (score 1):

You are right with the asumption that INTEGER is mapped to NUMBER(38) up to Oracle 10.2.

See
*ANSI Datatypes Converted to Oracle Datatypes*

**9.2**

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/sql_elements2a.htm#114927

**10.2**

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i54335

Starting with 11.2 the mapping is defined as

`INTEGER  NUMBER(p,0)`

**11.2**

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00213

**12.1**

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF55581

Unfortunately I can't find the definition of the `p`...

JDBC Driver is probably taking the `data_length` in case that the  `data_precision`is missing...

```
CREATE TABLE  "TABLE01"
(
   NUM_INT INTEGER
)
; 
CREATE TABLE  "TABLE02"
(
   NUM_INT NUMBER(38,0)
)
;
select TABLE_NAME, substr(DATA_TYPE,1,15) DATA_TYPE, DATA_LENGTH, DATA_PRECISION, DATA_SCALE 
from user_tab_columns where table_name like 'TABLE0_';

TABLE_NAME                     DATA_TYPE       DATA_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
------------------------------ --------------- ----------- -------------- ----------
TABLE01                        NUMBER                   22                         0 
TABLE03                        NUMBER                   22             38          0
```

`Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production`

**My interpretation**

1) `p` in `NUMBER(p,0)`is not documented and therefor set to `null

2) JDBC driver sees no precisions so takes the length instead of it.

I'm not sure if this is absolute correct behavior, but I'd try to avois the usage of non-Oracle data types if possible.